# Android: Activity automatically finishes after one minute?

Tags: android, android-activity, timer

How can I add functionality to my activity that it **automatically finishes after one minute?**

I.e. I am creating a mathematical game where the user needs to get so many correct answers within a minute. I have created everything else but am unsure how to add the **timer/Countdown?**

I seen the following on the android website:

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("done!");
         }
      }.start();
```

But I am unsure how to use this code, is it used within oncreate?

Comment: Show some code that you have written

Comment: please see the post, i made an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Handler`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //finish is here
        }
    }, 60000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Where would I add the intent for a new activity to open up after the minute is up?

Comment: @Rjni2014 you're welcome. You can add it where I've added the comment `finish is here`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to show the countdown within the activity using this method? I.e. within a text box/edit text

Comment: @Rjni2014 this is not a chat. One question - one answer.

Comment: OK, I am not able to use intents within the run method? I am getting an error